# Android CalendarView: How to open a new activity with each date click?

Tags: java, android, view, calendar, calendarview

How do I open a new activity when each date is clicked? I know there is an onSelectedDateChange method, but I don't know how to get it to open a new activity.

What I really want it to do is to open a different activity for each day, but I can settle for each day to share the same activity.

Is there a way to accomplish this? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: well do you know how to start a new activity? its the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to get it to open a new activity

Call `startActivity()` on your `Activity` or other `Context`, specifying an `Intent` identifying the activity that you wish to start.

Note that this is how you start *any* activity, not just from within this particular event callback method.

Also note that since [`onSelectedDayChange()` is passed the `CalendarView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener.html#onSelectedDayChange%28android.widget.CalendarView,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), you can call `getContext()` on the `CalendarView` to get a `Context` suitable for use in calling `startActivity()`, if you like.

> What I really want it to do is to open a different activity for each day

There are an indeterminate number of days left in the universe, and you cannot have an indeterminate number of activities. Instead, pass the date to your activity via an `Intent` extra, and pick it up in the activity that you start up.